# Remi PHP-FPM Dbase

Tags: linux, centos, php, dbase

I need to open some *.dbf files. I know what PHP has that module for easily work with such files, but how i can add that module to php-fpm ?

```
[root@mcs-team tmp]# pecl install dbase
downloading dbase-5.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download dbase-5.1.0.tgz (14,112 bytes)
.....done: 14,112 bytes
12 source files, building
running: phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Also,

```
* Sun Aug 10 2008 Remi Collet <rpms@famillecollet.com> 5.3.0-0.1.alpha2-dev.200808101630.fc9.remi
  - new snapshot (5.3.0alpha2-dev) 
  - no more dbase extension
```

Why, and how i can get it ?

```
[root@mcs-team tmp]# php -v
PHP 5.4.12 (cli) (built: Feb 20 2013 14:41:12)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

[root@mcs-team tmp]# uname -a
Linux mcs-team.tld 2.6.32-042stab063.2 #1 SMP Tue Oct 23 16:24:09 MSK 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@mcs-team ~]# cat /etc/*elease*
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum install php-dev*
pecl install dbase
```